# How does searchvim work?

Tags: linux, search, vim, plugins, vim-plugin

Has anyone use searchvim plugin? I am using it and when I press `<tab>` inside the search I get a "scanning tags message" and seems to go indexing all files in a project and only if I press `CTRL-C` it shows the result, which is a word in the file I am searching.
Is this supposed to work like that? Does not seem to be very useful. I want autocomplete for searching in my current file. Not all included files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that plugin, but it looks like you can influence the completion behavior through the built-in `'complete'` option. To remove the tags lookup (which can take a long time, especially with many or large tags databases)

```
:set complete-=t
```

See `:help 'complete'` for details.

Maybe you can alternatively reconfigure the plugin to use a completion other than the `i_CTRL-N` one, e.g. buffer-local completion `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N`.

Comment: What is `i_CTRL-N` and `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N`? Are the insert mode and CTRL+N?

Comment: I used the `:help` topic names; yes, this is (Ctrl+X) Ctrl+N in insert mode.